# Misspelled cardholders name: any official policy of MasterCard?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, consumer-protection, mastercard

My bank issued a MasterCard debit card with a misspelled cardholder name. They promise that credit card regulations allow up to 3(?) letters to be misspelled in the name, but can't show an official policy of credit card company.

**Is there any official policy on cardholder misspellings for MasterCard?**

The bank is ready to re-issue the card with a correct spelling, I am just wondering whether it's worth my time and hassle.

Comment: Say it's ok. Why risk a merchant rejecting based on the signature not matching? This is really a simple thing to just fix and not wonder if and when it will present itself as an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that the average cashier may not know the regulation. If it is misspelled and they notice it, they could reject the card when they compare the ID.

The question is how often do they check ID's? Answer: not very often.

Also remember that the most online forms ask for the name on the card. So which name are you supposed to enter: the correct name or the wrong name? Keep in mind that you will have to misspell your name for years.

I would ask for it to be corrected. The account number should not change.

Comment: I would rather wait a few days for a new card than worry about potentially explaining myself a few times each year.